# Background in framed legend

Tags: plotting, legending

i'm trying to set a white background in my framed lagend, soh that it could overlap the curves. Note that in the left corner on the top of the frame there are curves inside the legend. I would like to know how to color this frame in white, so that curves couldn't appear above it. Thanks!

[image]

i am using this configuration:

```
ListLogPlot[{sim[[1]], sim[[2]], sim[[3]], sim[[4]], sim[[5]], 
sim[[6]], sim[[7]], sim[[8]], sim[[9]]}, 
DataRange -> {snrdBMin, snrdBMax}, 
PlotRange -> {{snrdBMin, snrdBMax}, {10^-8, 1}}, Axes -> False, 
Joined -> {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}, 
PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", "\[FilledCircle]", 
"\[FilledCircle]", "\[FilledCircle]", "\[FilledCircle]", 
"\[FilledCircle]", "\[FilledCircle]", 
"\[FilledCircle]"},(*BaseStyle\[Rule]{FontSize\[Rule]16},*)
PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red], Directive[Red, Dashed], 
Directive[Blue], Directive[Blue, Dashed], Directive[Darker[Green]],
Directive[Darker[Green], Dashed], Directive[Black], 
Directive[Black, Dashed]}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"SNR", "OP"}, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 16], 
AspectRatio -> 0.85,
PlotLegends -> 
Placed[LineLegend[{Directive[Red], Directive[Red, Dashed], 
 Directive[Blue], Directive[Blue, Dashed], 
 Directive[Darker[Green]], Directive[Darker[Green], Dashed], 
 Directive[Black], 
 Directive[Black, Dashed]}, {"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL", "OOO", 
 "PPP", "QQQ", "RRR", "SSS", "TTT", "UUU"}, Joined -> True, 
 LegendMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", "\[FilledCircle]", 
  "\[FilledCircle]", "\[FilledCircle]", "\[FilledCircle]", 
  "\[FilledCircle]", "\[FilledCircle]", "\[FilledCircle]"}, 
  LegendFunction -> Framed, LegendMargins -> {{2, 2}, {2, 2}}, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 20, 20, 20}], {{0.01, 0.01}, {0, 0}}]]
```

Comment: Try modifying your `LineLegend[]`: `LineLegend[directives, strings, Background -> White, opts]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use (say) `Framed` to provide the `LegendFunction` option, for the plot, you can pass the `Background -> White` option to it, like so:

```
pts = Through[{Sin, Cos}[Range[0, 2, 0.1]]];
ListPlot[pts, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"AAA", "BBB"}, 
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0, 
        Background -> White] & )], {Right, Bottom}],
 Frame -> True
]
```

[image: plot with legend]