# Plotting NDSolve solutions for an ODE with a variable parameter

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

Quick question!
I'm supposed to plot solution curves for the ODE *y'(t)+nty(t)* = 0, *y(0)* = 3 with integer *n* varying from 1 to 6 inclusive. In the process, I have to use interpolated functions obtained via *NDSolve*, even though the ODE in question does have analytical solutions. The final plot should look like this:
[image]

I got the graph above using Matlab, which I'm familiar with, but I'm a newbie in the Wolfram language. I began by stating the ODE:

```
diffEq = y'[t] + n*t*y[t] == 0
```

Then, I could use *DSolve* and obtain the analytical solution of the ODE in symbolic form with *n* as a parameter and proceed to plot the 6 curves, but, as mentioned above, I have to use *NDSolve* instead. Typing

```
NDSolve[{diffEq, y[0] == 3}, y[t], {t, 4}]
```

is no use because *NDSolve* needs numerical data, and the program cannot generate any without knowing the value of *n*. I could use a *For* or *Table*, but I still don't know how to use these commands appropriately. Some help would be great.

Comment: Use `ParametricNDSolve`

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html)

```
pNDSolveValue = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] + n t y[t] == 0, y[0] == 3}, 
  y[t], {t, 4}, {n}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Table[pNDSolveValue[n], {n, 1, 6}], {t, 0, 4}, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {t, y[t]}), 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[PromptForm[n, #] & /@ Range[6], Scaled[{.8, .6}]], 
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> could use a For or Table, but I still don't know how to use these
> commands appropriately.

One possibility.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ode = y'[t] + n*t*y[t] == 0;
sols = Table[First@NDSolve[{ode, y[0] == 3}, y, {t, 4}], {n, 1, 6}];
leg = Table[Row[{"n = ", n}], {n, 1, 6}];
leg = Placed[LineLegend[leg, 
        LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0, 
        Background -> White] &)], {Right, Top}];

Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. sols], {t, 0, 4}, AxesLabel -> {"time", "y(t)"},
 PlotLegends -> leg,
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed, Dashing[0.003]],
 BaseStyle -> 12, ImageSize -> 400]
```

References: The trick to put white background for legend frame thanks to this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170122/background-in-framed-legend)